# What is the proper Swift-UI way for sizing UI elements in extracted subviews?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Supposing I have the main view of my application and I need to create many different images, texts, buttons, textfields, ... with proper sizes to get a neat layout - device independently.

My current approach was to work with GeometryReader to get the screen-sizes (width, height) of the device and based on this I compute their sizes.

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ...
            VStack {
                Subview1(g, ...)
            }
            ...
            HStack {
                Subview2(g, ...)

                ...

                Subview7(g, ...)
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**One of the many subviews as example:**

```
struct Subview5: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy
    ...

    var body: some View {
        Image(...)
            .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.5, height: g.height * 0.3)
    }
}
```

So with passing the geometry of the main view to the extracted subviews the code gets more and more difficult to read.

Is there another more elegant or a typical Swift-UI way doing this?

Thank you for taking your time in answering my question!

Comment: *Hopefully* you don't need `GeometryReader` in all of your subviews like that. I would think that the `Image` might be one of the relatively few cases. I would try to layout everything with SwiftUI stacks and then constrain things as needed with `.frame(maxWidth:, maxHeight:)` (and related modifiers) and only use `GeometryReader` within a subview when it is specifically needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For example at buttons specifying `maxWidth: , maxHeight:` you would use for example `UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100` or  `UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1` to get desired proportional sizes?

Comment: In your first example, I’d use padding — not basing it on so width -100. In the second example, is there *really* a time when you want it to be .1 the height of the screen? If so, use GeometryReader there. I’ve never used UIScreen in a SwiftUI project — there’s always a way around it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concise input, you helped me a lot! @jnpdx